# Reference (foundamental sol. and grad estimate, etc.): a particular elliptic PDE

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, fourier-analysis, elliptic-pde

In $\mathbb{R}^d$, consider the following equation
$$\Delta u -x\cdot \nabla u = f $$
where $f$ can be $C^\infty$ and decay like $e^{-\frac{c|x|^2}{2}}$.

I would like to know fundamental sol. to this equation or some gradient estimate, preferably pointwise. In particular I'm interested in the following quantity
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|\nabla u|^2e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{2}}dx.
\end{align*}

One useful observation might be
$$\nabla \cdot (e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{2}}\nabla u)=f e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{2}} .$$

Thank you!

Comment: This is called Ornstein–Uhlenbeck evolution, and it has been studied *a lot*. In particular, an explicit solution is known in terms of the usual heat semigroup.